# How to make cell index path.row == an items index in array?

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I have an array of 100 items called `cellNames` of type String. I have a collection view made up of 1 section with 100 `customCollectionViewCell` rows in it. I'm looking for something like this-

```
for cellName in cellNames {
   if cellName.index == cellNames[indexpath.row] {
     let cellName = cell.nameTextField
    }
}
```

So in summation I need the `cellName` for index 0...100 == cellForRowAt 0...100

Comment: Do you want to populate your collectionView with `cellNames`? It is unclear what you are asking

Comment: My collection view has 100 cells: CustomCollectionViewCell. the customcollectionviewcell has a text field called nameTextField. I need to take each of the 100 items from the array and populate each cell with one cellName from the array. but I need them in order so that cellName[0] populates cell@[indexPath.row[0]]

Comment: What do you want? Do you want to combine every cell with the indexpath or do yon want to know which cell is the 3rd for example

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are creating 100 static cells and trying to populate them with `cellNames`. A correct approach would be to conform to `UICollectionViewDataSource` and set the number of items to `cellNames`'s count and use the indexPath provided in `cellForItemAt` to access each element of your array.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let cellNames = ["1", "2", "3"] // ....

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellNames.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCellId", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        let cellName = cellNames[indexPath.item]
        cell.nameTextField.text = cellName
        return cell
    }
}
```